# Odd behaviour of dnsmasq across docker containers

Tags: docker, coreos, alpine-linux, dnsmasq, confd

I have a CoreOS instance running a docker container which runs `dnsmasq`. Currently the `dnsmasq` configuration only set to log all queries and to run in debug mode, so it should just do the caching.

When I try to use this from a different container with `dig`, `nslookup`, or simply running `ping google.com` i get back `Bad hostname: google.com` and I can see in the log query that requests are coming in multiple times, as if being retried.

If I try to run same commands from the host machine running CoreOS, everything resolves no problem in single try.

My plan is to run the `dnsmasq` on each CoreOS machine in the cluster, and to have it backed by `confd`, so that all services can resolve appropriate counterparts.

I'm using Alpine linux for my base images, but I tried to run those commands inside an Ubuntu and a Debian image with the same result.

Comment: "so that all services can resolve appropriate counterparts"; be aware that docker 1.9 allows you to directly resolve other containers on the same network through their name. (e.g. `ping other-container`). Docker 1.10 has additional enhancements for that and allows you to set "container scoped aliases" and "network scoped aliases" for containers.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware, however, it's going to be part of CoreOS cluster, so I'm not sure how Docker will communicate that across multiple hosts. We're also planning to run CoreOS + Flannel, so each container gets a routable IP address, I think this mechanism is also outside of Docker's purview.

Comment: So, I'm getting closer to the answer. I've ran `nslookup` through `strace` inside one of the containers and one line was particularly interesting - `reply from unexpected source: 172.17.42.1#53, expected 10.137.64.102#53` Basically, the `10.` address is passed to the container as it's `--dns`. But the responses come from the host's `docker` network adapter, so it's being discarded and retried. When I set the resolver as an IP on internal docker network it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The right thing to do was present in the following thread ([Setting Up Docker Dnsmasq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23012273/setting-up-docker-dnsmasq))

when exposing the port it should be explicitly bound to an IP address of the host (internal, in our case).

Invocation of the container looks something like this:

```
source /etc/environment
docker run -d --cap-add NET_ADMIN \
    -p "$COREOS_PRIVATE_IPV4:53:53" \
    -p "$COREOS_PRIVATE_IPV4:53:53/udp" \
    -e COREOS_PRIVATE_IPV4="$COREOS_PRIVATE_IPV4"\
    someorg/dnsmasq
```

Then all containers that are ran with `--dns "$COREOS_PRIVATE_IPV4"` get to resolve via machine-level dnsmasq correctly.