# How can I add hostnames to a container on the same docker network?

Tags: docker, hostname, docker-compose

Suppose I have a docker compose file with two containers. Both reference each other in their /etc/hosts file. Container A has a reference for container B and vice versa. And all of this happens automatically. Now I want to add one or more hostnames to B in A's hosts file. How can I go about doing this? Is there a special way I can achieve this in Docker Compose?

Example:

172.0.10.166 service-b my-custom-hostname

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes.  In your compose file, you can specify [network aliases](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#aliases).

```yaml
services:
  db:
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - database
          - postgres
```

In this example, the `db` service could be reached by other containers on the default network using `db`, `database`, or `postgres`.

You can also [add aliases to running containers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_connect/) using the `docker network connect` command with the `--alias=` option.

Comment: Are you sure that you can add DNS alias when container is running? The closest option that I have achieved is to still disconnect container from the network and add it again with alias. Commands: `docker network list` , `docker network disconnect dns-alias-network my-centos-container` , `docker network connect --alias my-centos-alias dns-alias-network my-centos-container` . Any options to avoid disconnecting container? - `Error response from daemon: endpoint with name my-centos already exists in network dns-alias-network`

Comment: @Laimis Yes, you can alias a container while it is running; disconnecting it from the network doesn't stop the container.  I don't know if there is a way to add the alias without disconnecting the container, though.

Comment: @Steve yeah, that disconnect & connect trick worked. Would be curious if this is hard network glitch. For instance, the question is whether TCP connections are just delayed for milliseconds/reconnected gracefully or not.

Comment: You save my bacon hehehe

Answer (score 11):

Docker compose has an [extra_hosts](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extra-hosts) feature that allows additional entries to be added to the container's host file.

## Example

### docker-compose.yml

```
web1:
  image: tomcat:8.0
  ports:
    - 8081:8080
  extra_hosts:
    - "somehost:162.242.195.82"
    - "otherhost:50.31.209.229"
web2:
  image: tomcat:8.0
  ports:
    - 8082:8080
web3:
  image: tomcat:8.0
  ports:
    - 8083:8080
```

### Demonstrate host file entries

Run docker compose with the new [docker 1.9 networking feature](http://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/get-started-overlay/):

```
$ docker-compose --x-networking up -d
Starting tmp_web1_1
Starting tmp_web2_1
Starting tmp_web3_1
```

and look at the hosts file in the first container. Shows the other containers, plus the additional custom entries:

```
$ docker exec tmp_web1_1 cat /etc/hosts 
..
172.18.0.4  web1
172.18.0.2  tmp_web2_1
172.18.0.3  tmp_web3_1
50.31.209.229   otherhost
162.242.195.82  somehost
```

Comment: Close! Thanks for the writeup. What I really want is this: 172.18.0.2 tmp_web2_1 otherhost somehost

Comment: I want to reference a container not some static IP address

Comment: @saada Ahh, gotcha you want aliases. Don't think that is supported

Comment: @saada You could fudge it by specifying a container name: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#container-name

Comment: Ah but using container name limits the scale feature which is a nono for me. I guess this is worth putting on the compose issues

Comment: @saada It's tricky either way. If you do want container scaling, you can't have a fixed name either, explaining why compose appends a number to the generated container name.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you can pass a host name referenced in your host's /etc/hosts file via --add-host flag :

```
$ docker run ... --add-host="droid"
```

Your host's /etc/hosts would need the following entry:
    xx.xx.xx.xx    droid

Of course, xx.xx.xx.xx will need to be reachable from inside the container you just started using the 'docker run' command. You can have one or more --add-host="xyz".

More details about --add-host here:

http://docs.docker.com/v1.8/reference/commandline/run/

Comment: How can I define another container's runtime ip address in this format?

Comment: You can add multiple --add-host flags. All values can go in that container's host's /etc/hosts (or they can be in a local name server).

Comment: I'm trying to reference a dynamic IP not a static one