# How do i get my two docker containers to communicate with each other?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, spring-mvc, containers

How do I get my two docker containers to communicate with each other on Localhost?

I have separated out my project into a backend and a front-end. I am now trying to run both parts in separate docker containers however i get a connection refused. I tried running both on a docker network but it didn't seem to work.

Both my Dockerfiles look like

```
COPY ./build/libs/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /usr/app/

WORKDIR /usr/app

RUN sh -c 'touch demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar'

RUN apk add --update \
    curl \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

and the front end makes calls to the back end by

```
protected <T> ResponseEntity<T> getRequest(String path, Class<T> responseType) {
        return restTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:8090/" + path, responseType);
    }
```

but i get a

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

I run both my container via:

```
docker run -p 8090:8090 -d repo/back-end
docker run -p 8080:8080 -d repo/front-end
```

Comment: Use docker compose. Create a network. Refer to containers by name. They are definitely **not** localhost.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In docker-compose how to create an alias / link to localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43579740/in-docker-compose-how-to-create-an-alias-link-to-localhost)

Answer (score 0):

In docker you can create your own network:

```
docker network create myNetwork
```

And run containers inside this network using `--net` and `--name` flags:

```
docker run -d -p 8000:8000 --net myNetwork --name backend backend-image
docker run -d -p 8001:8001 --net myNetwork frontend-image
```

Then you should be able to access backend using `http://backend:8000` url from your frontend container.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks both for the responses, i added a docker-compose.yml in frontend

```
version: '3'
services:
  frontend:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: myNetwork
```

and in backend

```
version: '3'
services:
  backend:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8090:8090"
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: myNetwork
```

and then changed my rest service to make calls to

```
private static final String prefix = "http://backend:8090/";
```

Comment: The point of `docker-compose` is to **compose** sets of containers. Having a separate file for each container rather misses this point.

Comment: If I have both parts stored in a separate repo, how could this be achieved using only one compose file?

Comment: That same way it works with Java libraries. Push the two separate containers up to a repository and then pull them down in a third project.