# Curl from one container to a domain in a nginx container

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have a simple node script that runs in a container and a nginx container running 2 different web-sites (let's call them `default.example.com` and `foobar.example.com`). `default.example.com` is configured a the default host in the nginx file.

So when I make a call to `http://nginx` from my node container, I will reach the `default.example.com` page. But how can I curl the `foobar.example.com` from the node container?

I think I have to pass the domains in my docker compose file so the containers know where the following request will go, but I haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `Host` header? So: `curl -H 'Host: foobar.example.com' http://nginx`. This should even work with IP instead of "nginx"... Also, checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39707966/3727050) for adding hostnames/aliases to a container

Comment: @urban this worked. But is there also a way to tell docker where to route? In my node container I can only pass a domain to the program (so either `http://nginx` or `http://foobar.example.com` and can't modify the header.

Comment: Check the link above. I have not tried it so not sure how it works, but it seems that network aliases allows you to add multiple FQDNs on the same container

Comment: Adding aliases to the network causes a non responding curl result.

Comment: Hmm, the only other thing I can think of is setting aliases within the container in `/etc/hosts` (`extra_hosts` in docker-compose) - details [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extra_hosts). That should be configured in the client box

Comment: you could create just directive on your default nginx website like `/foobar` and host the app there rather on seperate url