# How to give multiple hostnames to a container in docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've an application that uses custom hosts. For example user1.app user2.app user3.app.

In a traditional dev environment running on my computer I add all those entries to /etc/hosts file pointing to 127.0.0.1

For automatic testing purpose I need that a single docker container is referenced with multiple host using docker-compose.

On docker-compose each service receive a hostname as the service name and I can ping to other containers using the service name, but how I can give a container multiple hostnames?

The --add-host or extra_host doesn't seems to be the solution because I don't know the docker ip address that will be used for that service.

Comment: You can use network aliases: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39707966/13806326

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to:

- Have same container on the same network
- Use aliases setting to add more hosts to the service.

on the first `docker-compose.yml` file

```
services:
  one:
    ...
    networks:
      - my-network

networks:
  my-network:
    driver: bridge
    name: my-network # This is to not prefix the project name (directory_name)
```

on the other `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
services:
  two:
    networks:
      my-network:
        aliases:
          - dos
          - bbb
networks:
  my-network:
    external: true # it was created by other compose file
```

this way service `one` can access to service `two` by using any of this host:

- two
- dos
- bbb

This can be tested with:

```
$ docker-compose run one ping two
$ docker-compose run one ping dos
$ docker-compose run one ping bbb
```

All should return pings reply.

More on this here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#aliases